# unable load python package when executing python script from c#

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

Hi i'm new to python and ironPython, I'm trying to execute the python script from c#, i can execute the script from python Interactive window succesfully but i'm unable execute the script from c#. i can execute the python script from c# which basic functionalities but i can't execute my script because my uses some package's like numpy, keras, tensorflow, sk-learn, pandas, etc., i'm getting error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\amarn\Downloads\Projects\AI_Score\Ai_Score\AI_Score.py", line 1, in <module>
import keras
File "C:\Users\amarn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import utils
File "C:\Users\amarn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from . import np_utils
File "C:\Users\amarn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\np_utils.py", line 6, in <module>
import numpy as np
File "C:\Users\amarn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
from . import _distributor_init
File "C:\Users\amarn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

so can anyone help me what i have to do and also i want to know why these package not loading python.exe which is executing from c# code.
This is my C# code:

```
public static void RunPythonScript()
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo pythonInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            pythonInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\amarn\Anaconda3\python.exe";
            var file1 = "C:/Users/amarn/source/repos/IBBI Crawling And Ai_Score/IBBI Crawling/bin/Debug/InsolvencyCompany_20190627T181821.xlsx".Replace(" ","%20");
            string PredictFile_file2 = "C:/Users/amarn/source/repos/IBBI Crawling And Ai_Score/IBBI Crawling/bin/Debug/InsolvencyCompany_Predict_20190627T181821.xlsx".Replace(" ", "%20");
            var script = string.Format(@"C:\Users\amarn\Downloads\Projects\AI_Score\AI_Score\AI_Score.py {0} {1}", file1, PredictFile_file2);
            pythonInfo.Arguments = script;

            pythonInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pythonInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            pythonInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pythonInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
            pythonInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo = pythonInfo;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();

                var errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                var results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errors))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Erros: " + errors);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Result: \n" + results);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you running it at the command prompt.. changing folder and running "AI_Score.py" or, "path\to\python.exe AI_Score.py"? or something else?  as you dont specify a default folder, the folder you are in is possibly different in c# compared to when you ran it at the command line

Comment: i have run from visual studio interactive window it is executing but i run from python.exe from a folder its showing same error

Comment: then you need to fix the python side, and worry less how by some voodoo that it works inside the interactive window.. with the info shown I cant make any better suggestion than it either has to do with pathing, or, current directory..

Comment: the python that i have installed using anaconda from there i have executed the code it not working after that i have installed python directly and install packages manually then its working. so can i know why it is happened